# Enable JSON to retrieve data from WSO2 Data service

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am using wso2dss-3.0.0 and how can I enable JSON to retrieve data from WSO2 Data service?

Given that I am able to get data in XML Format. 
When I create the query XML and RDF formats are available as output types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [blog](http://lafernando.com/2011/11/27/json-data-services-using-wso2-dss/) on how to get json response from WSO2 DSS.